# How to sum all aggregate value SQL- Laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to some selected column. I have tried to sum for `fee`. But it throws an error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'service_fee' in field
>   list is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from..........

I have tried below way. Can anybody help with this? Thanks in advance.

```
$events = Event::select($columns)->EventComplete()
            ->where('events.event_end_date', '<', $currentDate)
            ->where('events.have_balance', '>', 0)
            ->join('role_users_details as rud', 'events.promoter_id', '=', 'rud.id')
            ->join('transaction as tra', 'events.id', '=', 'tra.event_id', 'left outer')
            ->join(\DB::raw("(select tran.id as ttid, sum(tran.ticket_price) as total_amt, sum(tran.ticket_service_fee) as service_fee, tran.order_service_fee as order_service_fee,tran.order_service_fee_per as order_service_fee_per , count('ticket_order.*') as total_tickets
    from `transaction` as `tran`
    right join `ticket_order` on `tran`.`id` = `ticket_order`.`transaction_id`
    where `ticket_order`.`status` = 1 group by `ttid`) as tt"), 'tt.ttid', '=', 'tra.id', 'left outer  ')
            ->selectRaw('CONCAT_WS(" ", rud.first_name, rud.middle_name, rud.last_name) as promoter')
            ->selectRaw('sum(tt.total_amt) as tickets')
            ->selectRaw('sum(tt.service_fee) as service_fee')
            ->selectRaw('sum(tt.order_service_fee) as order_fee')
            ->selectRaw('sum(tt.order_service_fee_per) as order_fee_per')
            ->selectRaw('sum(tt.total_tickets) as total_tickets')
            ->selectRaw('(service_fee + order_fee + order_fee_per) as fee')
            ->selectRaw('FROM_UNIXTIME(events.event_end_date, "%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s") as ending_date')
            ->groupBy('events.id');
```

Comment: Have you  tried qualifying this (service_fee + order_fee + order_fee_per) ??

Comment: can you share all query builder code ?

Comment: @C2486 Please see the updated question.

Comment: did you try and run by comment `->selectRaw('(service_fee + order_fee + order_fee_per) as fee')` ?

Comment: @C2486 Yes, Its working without that line. I need to some these value and keep it `as fee`. How can i do that?

Comment: your column name and alias name is same. Try with different alias name instead of service_fee.

Comment: @VishalGupta I need to sum these alias name(service_fee + order_fee + order_fee_per) and give a name anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just add all the sums together?

```
->selectRaw('sum(tt.service_fee) + sum(tt.order_service_fee) + sum(tt.order_service_fee_per) as fee')
```